# With IPN, how to filter Paypal payments for which the money has not arrived yet

Tags: security, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have an IPN script that **automatically sends** the download code of the product that was purchased, when the Paypal payment arrives.

But I forgot to filter Paypal payments for which the money has not arrived yet .... And the download code was sent to someone ... who will in fact **never pay**.

```
An eCheck payment from *** was declined by the sender's bank. We will 
automatically try to process this payment again in 3 business days. It then 
usually takes 3-5 days for the money to be deposited into your account. Please 
do not ship items until you receive payment.
```

I have lost this time (product sent, but I'll never get the money), but for next time :

**How to filter such delayed payments with Paypal IPN ?**

Comment: The customer is innocent of your premature allegation until proven guilty. The fault is yours. You sent the goods.

Comment: @EJP I have mailed him several times since this declined payment, and he never replied... and there was no money linked to this eCheck payment. I think this proves my allegation. Never mind: I have lost this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this code in my IPN script :

```
if (!($payment_status === 'Completed'))
{
  return;
}
```

This prevents the "download code" of my product to be sent in the case the status is not `Completed`. I hope it will work, and filter `Pending` payments...

Comment: Even better would be to check the payment_status and instead of simply ending the script, generate an email notification and/or update your database so the buyer knows what's going on.  Then when the payment clears you'll get another IPN with the updated status, and at that point you can have it process like any other completed payment.